# pointwise weak convergenge in $l^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $1 < p < \infty$. Let $x_{n} = (x_{n}^{j})$ and $x = (x^{j})$ be elements of $l^{p}$. Show that $Xn \rightharpoonup  x$ in $l^{p}$ if, and only if, $x_{n}^{j} \rightharpoonup  x^{j}$ for every positive integer j. I have the left to rigth but i don't know how to proceed with other direction. Some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. For example, $ne_n$ does not converge weakly even though its coordinates converge to those of $(0,0,...)$.

Suppose $(x_n^{j})$ is norm bounded. Then there exists $R>0$ such that the sequence is contained in the closed ball of radius $R$ around the origin.  This ball is a compact metric space under weak topology. [Combine Banach Alaoglu Theorem  with separability]. But the only possible limit point of the sequence is $(x^{j})$ because of coordinate-wise convergence. It follows that  $(x_n^{j})$ converges weakly to $(x^{j})$.

Comment: However, the the conclusion holds if you assume that the sequence is norm bounded. [I will add  a proof if you are interested]. @LMOTRU

Comment: @geetha290km yeah! i'm interested!

Comment: @LMOTRU I have added a proof.